# What would happen if I connected VCC of HX711 to 5V but DT and SCK go to ESP32 GPIO pins?

Tags: esp32, hx711

What would happen if I connected VCC of HX711 breakout board to 5V but DT and SCK go to any GPIO pins of ESP32? Would that damage the ESP32 GPIO pins because are rated for 3.3V?

Can consider the connection below but instead of VCC connected to 3V3 on ESP32, it is connected to 5V on ESP32.

[image]

Comment: then you'd have those pins connected. What is the actual question?

Comment: HX711 chip does not have a VCC pin. Nor a DT pin. It has DVDD and VSUP though. If you don't mean the HX711 chip but something else, then explain what you mean. If you use some module, refer to module documentation and then to the actual HX711 data sheet.

Comment: Supposedly esp32 gpio are 5V tolerant but it is not something i’d rely on for a commercial design - i’d be using level translators. But for a hobby project, it should ‘work’. Otherwise there’s plenty of level translator boards available.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the VCC of the breakout board directly powers the digital interface, it is wrong to connect 5V to it if you have a 3.3V MCU which does not tolerate 5V on input.

The 5V data out is not compatible with a 3.3V input which does not tolerate 5V. The datasheet does not mention specs, but either the 5V data output is weak and the MCU does not damage from overcurrent and overvoltage, or the 5V data output is strong and it will damage MCU pin with overcurrent and overvoltage. In either case, an unintentionally large current may flow out from HX711 data output pin and it may get damaged.

Again the datasheet shows no specs, but the HX711 clock input may expect 5V logic levels in and it may not be compatible with 3.3V output level from MCU. Or then it might work with 3.3V levels.